# Camera Flickering when rotating around character

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My camera is flickkering after rotating around a particular point. Can someone tell me what's the problem?
I have shared the image also, the image is flickkering a lot between scene frame and snipping tool frame[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDLgW.png)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollowMain : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
    [SerializeField] private float camMotionSpeed = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float camDistance = 1.5f;
    Vector3 offset;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //gets the distance between 2 vectors in vector format. 
        offset = (transform.position + target.position).normalized * camDistance; 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = target.position + offset;
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * camMotionSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
        offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * camMotionSpeed, Vector3.right) * offset;
        transform.LookAt(target.transform.position);
    }
}
```

I have tried out this code and I was expecting the camera to rotate around the character like that in GTA5

Answer (score 0):

The cause of "flickering" camera is "[Gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)" effect.

> **Gimbal lock** is the loss of one degree of freedom in a
> three-dimensional, three-gimbal mechanism that occurs when the axes of
> two of the three gimbals are driven into a parallel configuration,
> "locking" the system into rotation in a degenerate two-dimensional
> space.

In this code, I don't handle obstacles, only follow and observe the target:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
    
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float viewDistance = 1.5f;
    
    [Range(-90f, 90f)]
    [SerializeField] private float minVerticalAngle = -90f;
    [Range(-90f, 90f)]
    [SerializeField] private float maxVerticalAngle = 90f;
    
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSensitive = 10000f;
    [SerializeField] private float followingSensitive = 10000f;
    [SerializeField] private float distanceMovementSensitive = 10f;
    
    private Vector3 planarDirection;
    private float targetVerticalAngle;
    private Vector3 currentPosition;
    private float currentDistance;


    void Start()
    {
        planarDirection = Vector3.forward;
        targetVerticalAngle = 0f;
        currentPosition = target.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;
        var rotationInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"), 0f);
        var targetTransformUp = target.transform.rotation * Vector3.up;
        
        var rotationFromInput = Quaternion.Euler(targetTransformUp * (rotationInput.x * rotationSpeed));
        planarDirection = rotationFromInput * planarDirection;
        planarDirection = Vector3.Cross(targetTransformUp, Vector3.Cross(planarDirection, targetTransformUp));
        var planarRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(planarDirection, targetTransformUp);

        targetVerticalAngle -= (rotationInput.y * rotationSpeed);
        targetVerticalAngle = Mathf.Clamp(targetVerticalAngle, minVerticalAngle, maxVerticalAngle);
        
        var verticalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetVerticalAngle, 0, 0);
        var targetRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(
            transform.rotation,
            planarRotation * verticalRotation,
            1f - Mathf.Exp(-rotationSensitive * deltaTime));

        transform.rotation = targetRotation;
        
        currentPosition = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, target.position, 1f - Mathf.Exp(-followingSensitive * deltaTime));
        currentDistance = Mathf.Lerp(currentDistance, viewDistance, 1 - Mathf.Exp(-distanceMovementSensitive * deltaTime));
        transform.position = currentPosition - ((targetRotation * Vector3.forward) * currentDistance);
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest your answer is better than what chatGPT gave me, though the above code was written by me only

Comment: Also you can use 3rd person camera asset from asset store. Some of them are very good.

Comment: Yeah sure, I will give a try a later!