# How to rotate player camera via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I had my main camera as a component of my player object but I wanted to keep them separate so I created a script which allows for my camera to follow my player instead, while not keeping my camera as a child of the player object.

However, despite my player object itself being able to rotate properly, the camera does not follow it when I move my mouse horizontally, and only works vertically.

I currently have an empty game object with my main camera attached to it, with a reference to the player body (transform) and this following script:

```
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;

    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;

    float xRotation = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Make the camera follow the player
        transform.position = player.position + offset;

        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

    }
}
```

If I put this camera back under my player object and take out the line with the 'offset', it works, but with the camera on its own, it doesn't.

Comment: Script for [3rd person camera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75467289/12875862)

Comment: I will look into that. But my issue currently is that my camera will not rotate horizontally at all. Does the 'gimbal lock' apply here even though my code works when attached to my player?

Comment: It's not a gimbal lock issue here - you're simply not moving your camera in conjunction with `player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);`. So the camera script won't respond to any horizontal mouse movement. The reason why it works when parented under the player is that the player's transform will implicitly rotate and translate the camera when the player is moved. But with the camera as a separate object, you will have to do those calculations yourself.

Comment: I'll do some more testing but as of now, would transform.eulerAngles with my mouseY and mouseX as variables be the way to go?

Comment: It depends - what kind of behaviour do you want your camera to have? If it's meant to float behind the player like in a third-person shooter or GTA, then most approaches would recommend calculate the ideal virtual position above/behind the player (you could either do this in local space then transform it to world space, or calculate based on the player's transform.forward), move the camera there, then use [Transform.LookAt()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) to point the camera at the player.

Comment: Oh sorry I should have mentioned this in my post. This is for a first person camera with a character controller. I have just altered my code. I took out my Vector3.up rotate and replaced it with transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3 + mouse variables, but my camera shakes A LOT when moving horizontally and still does not budge much.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `Time.fixedDeltaTime` here - that's meant to relate to physics update cycles which are not always in sync with the game update loop. In the Update method, you'll want to use `Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: For some reason when I had time.deltaTime previously, I would notice brief stuttering with my camera. I changed it to fixedDeltaTime (per a suggestion) and all the stuttering was gone. I'm not sure how to fix the stuttering with deltaTime as opposed to fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.

Instead of

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
```

Try doing

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, player.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0f);
```

(edited)

So that the camera follows the Y rotation of the player as well, not just the position.

Hope this helps!

Alexa

Comment: Would've answered sooner, but I was given a 30 minute cooldown

Comment: Thanks for the help. So far I'm getting a "Quaternion does not contain a definiton of "'euler'" error on the lowercase 'euler' and it's an error I haven't seen before so I'm currently trying to find a work around for that

Comment: I changed the player.rotation.euler.y line to player.rotation.eulerAngles.y and so far everything works as it should. Not sure if that's an appropriate way for me to go about it though, but if it is thanks a lot

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. I wrote the script from memory without making sure it's right. Seems I was mistaken °_°'

Comment: It's alright, thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

Camera isn't rotating, because You rotate player object in script, not the camera-attached object. And You havn't any references in script on player horizontal rotation.
3DartBlade in first comment shows You how to make camera and player horizontal rotations equal [  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, player.rotation.euler.y, 0f);  ] , but if You have offset from player, You wouldn't get desired behaviour of camera in such way.
Easyest way to achive desired behaviour (3D-person camera) is creating one more empty object with script:

```
public Transform player;
private void LateUpdate() {
    transform.position = player.transform.position;
    transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation;
}
```

And make Your empty object with attached camera child of previous object, with next script on it:

```
public Vector3 offset;
public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
float xRotation = 0f;
void Start() {
    transform.position = cube.position + offset;
}
private void LateUpdate() {
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    xRotation -= mouseY;
    xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
}
```

And, after that done, You should implement player rotation around Y-axis in PlayerController script. Controlling player in camera-controlling script make no sense. You can, of course, but it can make great problems in future.

And few notes:

1. You should move, or rotate Your Camera in LateUpdate() method, not in Update(). Because, otherwise it could lead to camera jittering.
2. NOT use Time.fixedDeltaTime in Update() or LateUpdate() methods. It make no sense and can lead to weard behaviours. Use it in FixedUpdate() method - when You work fith physics. In Update(), LateUpdate() use Time.deltaTime.
3. For advance and easy camera controll - using Cinemachine package is the best practice. You will loose some time to learn this tool (from 15 minutes to one hour), but it will make Your life much easyer in future.

Comment: Is cinemachine for new or old input system? My camera works properly now but also, when I use deltaTime I get stuttering but fixedDeltaTime seems to fix that. Any idea why?

Comment: Cinemachine can be used for both (old and new) input systems. It just nice tool, helping to control camera easely. You can watch this video, it answers on Your question in first 4 minuets:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=537B1kJp9YQ
Or i Can recommen to You more advanced, but longer guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pJQndtJ2rk0
And about camera stuttering - i think You have problem, named Jitterring. Just change transform of Your player in Update, and Camera transform in LateUpdate. Watch about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFQhpwc6cKE&t=88s

Comment: About why You SHOULD use Time.deltaTime instead of Time.fixedDeltaTime in Update() and LateUpdate() methods, I can't explain in few words, but this is essential. You can watch this beautiful video, from my favourite Unity blogger:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfIsp28TYAQ